# "sqlite3.operationalerror unrecognized token" error

Tags: python, sqlite, operationalerror

I have a project in which I have implement a Search Engine. Our guide suggested us to implement the code given in O' Reilly's Collective Intelligence 2007 book. This is a part of the code where a webpage is indexed. We are making use of Sqlite3 database. I get error in the last part of the code and even after researching a lot, I have had no success.

```py
    def addtoindex(self,url,soup):
     if self.isindexed(url): return
     print 'Indexing '+url
     # Get the individual words
     text=self.gettextonly(soup)
     words=self.separatewords(text)
     # Get the URL id
     urlid=self.getentryid('urllist','url',url)
     # Link each word to this url
     for i in range(len(words)):
      word=words[i]
      if word in ignorewords: continue
      wordid=self.getentryid('wordlist','word',word)
      self.con.execute("insert into wordlocation(urlid,wordid,location)\values (%d,%d,%d)" % (urlid,wordid,i))
```

I am getting the following error in the last line:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "[some symbol i don't know]"

Comment: possible duplicate of [sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "01T00" Python datestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160637/sqlite3-operationalerror-unrecognized-token-01t00-python-datestamp)

Comment: I tried that but it's not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the backslash from the SQL command.

In Python, `\v` specifies a control character (a vertical tab).

Comment: may be just a space is missing before values() ?