# Database API: How to deal with multi where condition in Python

Tags: python, database, oracle

Like this question [passing-param-to-db-execute-for-where-in-int-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253494/passing-param-to-db-execute-for-where-in-int-list)

But more where condition, how to deal with it?

```
select * from tbl where params1='p1' and params2='p2' and params3 in ('v1', 'v2', v3')
```

If I want pass params1, params2, params3 to SQL statement using [Python DB API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), any suggestion?

BTW: Database is Oracle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use SQL parameters for each value.

For the `in` statement, that means you need to generate the parameters:

```
sql = 'select * from tbl where params1=:params1 and params2=:params2 and params3 in ({})'.format(
    ', '.join(['params3_' + str(i) for i in range(len(params3_value))])
```

where I assume that `params3_value` is a list of values to test `params3` against. If `params3_value` is 3 elements (like `['v1', 'v2', 'v3']`) then the generated SQL will look like:

```
select * from tbl where params1=:params1 and params2=:params2 and params3 in (:params3_0, :params3_1, :params3_2)
```

Then pass those paramaters to the `cursor.execute()` call:

```
params = {'params1': params1_value, 'params2': params2_value}
for i, val in enumerate(params3_value):
    params['params3_' + str(i)] = value
cursor.execute(sql, {params})
```

I used the `:name` named SQL parameter style here as that is what the `cx_Oracle` uses. Consult your database connector documentation for the exact supported parameter styles.

The `:named` named SQL parameter style requires that you pass in parameters as a dictionary, so the above code generates the right keys for the `params3_value` items.