# Compare Python list to table rows

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have a Python list which looks like this:

```
[{'id': 5, 'field1': True}, {'id': 6, 'field1': False}]
```

It's just a list of dictionaries containing key/value pairs. I want to look up rows from a table in a Postgres database that match on `id` and differ on `field1`.

Say my table looks like:

```
id   field1
-----------
5    True
6    True
```

Only the second row should be in the result: it matches on `id = 6` but differs on `field1 = true`

Is there any way to achieve this with SQL or would I need to loop through it manually? My use case involves **a lot** of rows, and this process would be repeated many times, so I'm trying to find the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways to do this in PostgreSQL, using a `WHERE IN` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE id IN (5, 6) AND (id, field1) NOT IN ((5, True), (6, False))
```

or a `JOIN` to a values table:

```sql
SELECT test.*
FROM test
JOIN (VALUES (5, True), (6, False)) AS v(id, field1)
ON test.id = v.id AND test.field1 != v.field1
```

In both cases for your sample data the result is

```
id  field1
6   t
```

With large amounts of data I would expect the `JOIN` query to be most efficient.
You can build the `VALUES` part of the query using something like:

```py
ll = [{'id': 5, 'field1': True}, {'id': 6, 'field1': False}]
','.join(str(tuple(d.values())) for d in ll)
```

which for your sample data gives:

```
(5, True),(6, False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Facing one issue tho:

JOIN (VALUES ('0123456789', 5), ('5123456789', 3), ('9123456789', 5))

This is how it shows my sql query. However, when I try to execute it, I get the following error:

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'(''0123456789'', 5), (''5123456789'', 3), (''9123456789'', 5)'"
LINE 4: JOIN (VALUES '(''0123456789'', 5), (''5123456789'', 3), (''9...

As you can see, I'm using Django and trying to embed the string of tuples with %s (prepared statements)

Comment: You won’t be able to use the values string in a prepared query, you’ll need to instantiate each tuple  separately in the query. Perhaps something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253494/passing-param-to-db-execute-for-where-in-int-list

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks like a JSON array, which you can pass as is:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM   jsonb_array_elements('[{"id": 5, "field1": true}, {"id": 6, "field1": false}]'::jsonb) j(obj)
JOIN   tbl t ON t.id     =  (obj->>'id')::int
            AND t.field1 <> (obj->>'field1')::bool
```

The same as [prepared statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) (Python has its own feature for this):

```sql
PREPARE qr1(json) AS 
SELECT t.*
FROM   json_array_elements($1) j(obj)
JOIN   tbl t ON t.id     =  (obj->>'id')::int
            AND t.field1 <> (obj->>'field1')::bool;
```

Then:

```
EXECUTE qr1('[{"id": 5, "field1": true}, {"id": 6, "field1": false}]');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=926c9fbcaa799644ad0f8e91769894c8)*

Be sure to have an index on `tbl (id, field1)`.